# Somar uma coluna com condicional de outra tabela (power bi)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

olá!
estou com dificuldades para chegar na solução do meu problema.

Preciso somar a quantidade de faturamento de todas as notas.
porém, preciso descontar as notas fiscais anuladas, que ficam no banco de dados como registro.
utilizamos duas tabelas para o controle de notas fiscais: **notasfiscais(cabeçalho)** e **notasfiscaisitens(itens)**.

onde, a quantidade se encontra na tabela de itens, e a minha condicional(que determina se a nota está anulada ou não), está na tabela de cabeçalho.

ao criar uma medida para realizar esta soma, tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

`qtd_anulada = calculate(sum(notasfiscaisitens[quantidade]), notasfiscais[anulada]=1)`

onde, notasfiscais[anulada] = 1, quer dizer que a nota está anulada.

porém acaba não funcionando, e a medida fica em branco.

como consigo fazer esta soma, com este filtro/condicional de outra tabela, no power bi?

OBS: o relacionamento entre as tabelas **notasfiscais** e **notasfiscaisitens** é a coluna *id_nf* (1xN)

Answer (score -1):

Sua métrica funciona. A única atenção é que o campo de notasfiscais[anulada] deve ser do tipo inteiro para funcionar a métrica

[image: Print da minha tela]

Espero que funcione.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).